# Java - Graphics being erased after returning from method

Tags: java, graphics

```
public void graph()
{
    // Build the panel
    JFrame graphWindow = new JFrame();
    JPanel graphPanel = new JPanel();
    Graphics g;
    graphWindow.setTitle(inputField.getText());
    graphWindow.getContentPane().add(graphPanel,"Center");
    graphPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    graphWindow.setSize(600, 600);
    graphWindow.setLocation(200,300);
    graphWindow.setVisible(true);

    g = graphPanel.getGraphics();
    graphPanel.addMouseListener(this);
    g.setFont(new Font("Times Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));
    g.drawString("Test",100,100);
}
```

My issue is that when my program returns from the method, the drawing is erased and I'm left with a blank white window. If I capture the method in a while loop, it isn't erased. Is there some way to preserve the graphics after returning from the method?

Comment: Override `paintComponent` in your panel and put the drawing code in there.

Comment: Your JFrame variable is local to the method.  As such,  it's not visible outside it and becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: there are several issues with this code. One is the simple fact that `graphWindow` is never visible, thus no content will be shown at all. Another one is related to some basic issues with your way of painting. This tutorial should help with that point: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/

Comment: I have tried making them instance variables, but the result is the same. Also, my graph window is visible. It's the last line of the first block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a JFrame. Make it visible. Put a JPanel in it. Override `paintComponent` in the JPanel to draw whatever you are trying to draw.

For instance:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // drawing code using g
    }
};
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setContentPane(panel);
frame.setSize(600, 600);
frame.setLocation(200,300);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

As soon as the JPanel calls it's `paintComponent` method, it will replace your drawing with the default look of a panel. Instead, create your JPanel with a custom `paintComponent` method (you can do it as an anonymous class like the example below or create your own class extending from `JPanel`).

```
// Build the panel
JFrame graphWindow = new JFrame();
JPanel graphPanel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setFont(new Font("Times Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g.drawString("Test", 100, 100);
    }
};
graphWindow.setTitle("Blabla");
graphWindow.getContentPane().add(graphPanel, "Center");
graphPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
graphPanel.setOpaque(true); // make the JPanel opaque
graphWindow.setSize(600, 600);
graphWindow.setLocation(200, 300);
graphWindow.setVisible(true);
```

Also, I noticed that you want a white background. You have to make your JPanel opaque, to do so. I inserted a line in your code to do that.

Comment: It is ok to downvote an answer, but if you do, please leave a comment to let the poster know how to improve the answer (or future answers) or what you don't like about the answer. Basically, be constructive.